# Allow null values in fields of hive table

Tags: hive, avro

I am creating a hive table from a avro file stored in hdfs. And, this avro file has been generated from a mongodb collection. The thing is some of the fields have null values and I want my fields in the hive table to accept null values as well apart from what they are supposed to store (like int, string, array, etc.). I created the hive table using

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pub_avro
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
location "hdfs://path/to/avro_source_file"
TBLPROPERTIES (
'avro.schema.url'='hdfs://path/to/avro_schema.avsc');
```

This creates the table:

```
OK
Time taken: 0.32 seconds
```

But when I'm printing the fields, it gives me:

```
hive> select * from pub_avro limit 10;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found null, expecting array
Time taken: 0.532 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue of accepting null values in the hive table columns, but I still can't specify correct schema for mongoDB id field in the avro file. I have removed `_id` field from the avro file and while specifying type of fields, I used `null` with each field.

`{ "name":"field_name", "type":["string", "null"]}`
instead of
`{ "name":"field_name", "type":"string"}`

Edit:

I have got the schema of the mongoDB id with this one
`{"name": "_id", "type": [{"namespace": "._id", "type": "record", "name": "_id", "fields": [{"name": "oid", "type": ["string", "null"]}]}, "null"] }`

I got schema of the avro file using this script:

```
from hdfs.ext.avro import AvroReader, AvroWriter
from hdfs import InsecureClient
import json
client = InsecureClient('http://master:50070')
dir_path = '/path/to/avro/file'
with AvroReader(client, dir_path) as reader:
    schema = reader.schema

schema = json.dumps(schema)
print sc
```